# Using MEF in an Azure function App

Tags: c#, azure, mef, azure-functions, composition

I am trying to use MEF in my function app. My requirement is to access 5-10 external APIs, fetch,aggregate and return the data through an HTTP triggered function. I need to resolve the external dependencies dynamically based on some logic. These external components are already built and exported.  I need to import them along with metadata.

I observed that  `System.ComponentModel.Composition`assembly is already referenced in a default function app created in VS 2017. Not sure how to proceed. A sample setup code would be helpful if at all it is possible in Azure functions.

Comment: Someone has asked the similar [issue](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/550). I recommend you could use this sample [Simple Calculator MEF Application](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Simple-Calculator-MEF-1152654e/sourcecode?fileId=18843&pathId=1181778681) to work with your azure function app to narrow this issue.

Comment: I asked that question in azure-functions community.  No response though. https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/550

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your scenario, I created my Http Trigger function via VS2017 to test this issue. I followed the  [Simple Calculator MEF Application](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Simple-Calculator-MEF-1152654e/sourcecode?fileId=18843&pathId=1181778681). And here is the structure of my project and  as follows:

[image]

Without adding the extension lib which supports the Mod operation into the `Extensions` folder, you could retrieve the following result:

[image]

While added the `ExtendedOperations.dll`, the Mod operation could work as expected as follows:

[image]

On my local side, I added the path for initializing `DirectoryCatalog` via hard code. When deploying to azure side, your precompiled function lib would be deployed under `D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin>`, you could add your `Extensions` folder within it and use the following code for retrieving your extension folder:

```
Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME"), @"site\wwwroot\bin\<your-extensions-folder>")
```

Also, you could leverage [kudu](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/) and navigate to `D:\home\site\wwwroot\<your-function-name>`, then add your `Extensions` folder under it, then init your `DirectoryCatalog` with the path `Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME"), @"site\wwwroot\<your-function-name>\<your-extensions-folder>")`.

[image]